# A little problem geometry

Tags: geometry

We have this problem:
Triangle $ABC$ has points $E\in AC$ and $F \in AB$. How to place $E$ & $F$ so we have $AF=FE=FB$.

Answer (score 2):

$E$ is on the circle with diameter $[AB]$ and centre $F$. It is the second intersection point of this  circle with  line $(AC)$.

Comment: I made a mistake,E ∈ AC and F ∈ AB

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible if $E$ is distinct from $A$ or $B$. If you want $AF=EF=BF$ then points $A$, $B$, and $E$ must all lie on some circle with $F$ as the circle's center. But points $A$, $B$, and $E$ also lie along the same line $AB$. The three points cannot be on the same line and the same circle unless $E$ is $A$ or $E$ is $B$.

**EDIT**

If $F$ is on $AB$ and $E$ is on $AC$, then all you need to do is put $F$ in the middle of $AB$ so that $AF=FB$. Then construct a circle with center $F$ and diameter $AB$. Wherever this circle bisects line $AC$ or line $BC$ is where you can place point $E$. If there is no intersection other than $A$ and $B$ then the problem is not possible to solve if $E$ is not equal to $A$ or $B$, since it will be impossible for $EF$ to be large enough to be equal to $AF$ and $BF$.

Comment: I made a mistake,E ∈ AC and F ∈ AB

Comment: So $F$ is the midpoint of $[AB]$?

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason on earth this should be possible.

$AF = FB$ means that $F$ is the midpoint of $AB$.  There is only one way to do that and that can always be done. ($F$ simply the midpoint of $AB$).

$FE = AE$ only possible of $\angle A$ is acute and $AC > AE$.  There's no guarantee of either, much less both of those.  But if those are both true then there is one way to do that and it can be done. (Swing an arc from $F$ of length $AF = \frac 12 AB$ to where it intersects $AC$.)

...

Oh... I said this is only possible if $\angle A$ is acute and $AC > AE$.  I was assuming that you mean $F\in \overline {AC}$ to mean that $F$ is on the side of the triangle $\overline {AC}$ so that $F$ is between $A$ and $C$  and not *outside* the triangle on the extension of $\overline{AC}$ so that either $A$ is between $F$ and $C$ or $C$ is between $A$ and $F$ are that $F= A$ or that $F= C$.

If it is acceptable that $A$ is between $F$ and $C$ or that $C$ is between $A$ and $F$ or that $F=C$ or that $F=A$ then this can always be done exactly one way:

Swing an arc from $F$, the midpoint of $AB$ of length $\frac 12 AB=AE = EF$ to intersect $\overline {AC}$ and one of five things will occur. 1) if $\angle A$ is a right angle:  Then the arc will intersect at one point: $A$.  So $A = F$.  2) $\angle A$ is obtuse: Then the arc will intersect at $A$ and at $F$ where $A$ is between $F$ and $C$ and $F$ is not on the triangle.  3)$\angle A$ is acute and $AC< AE$ then the arc will intersect at $A$ and at $F$ where $C$ is between $A$ and $F$ and $F$ is not on the triangle.  4)$\angle A$ is acute and $AC = AE$ then the arc will intersect at $A$ and at $C$.  And $F = C$.  4)$\angle A$ is acute and $AC > AE$ then the arc will intersect at $A$ and at $F$ where $F$ is between $A$ and $C$ and $F$ is a point on the side of the triangle.